# Going back to initial statement on reset in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm learning Verilog and I was wondering, is there a mean to go back to an initial statement in case of a reset? Something like the pseudo-code below:

```
initial begin
    do initial stuff
end

always @(posedge clock) begin
    if(reset)
        go back to initial
    else 
        do stuff
    end
end
```

It will be a lot less typing if it was possible.

Comment: Are you looking for something synthesizable, or just for general modeling?

Comment: Hi, dave_59. Yes, it has to be synthesizable. Tks.

Comment: Could you add why you want initial over just having a reset.

Comment: Hi, @Morgan. It was just a curiosity, as many of times, my initial state is equal to reset state, then I thought it could save some typing if I just could go back to initial instead of repeating a lot of code in the reset.

Comment: @WDiniz, I find it more common to have one or the other, never seen both being used at the same time before, although nothing wrong with having both on FPGA. `initial` is good for FPGA initial states, and an async reset used on ASIC, connected to Power on Reset circuit.

Comment: Thks, @Morgan, I'll have that in mind when designing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a task:

```
task init_stuff;
    begin
       /* do initial stuff */
    end
endtask

initial begin
    init_stuff;
end

always @(posedge clock) begin
    if(reset) begin
        init_stuff;
    end else begin
        /* do stuff */
    end
end
```

However, for synthesizable code you should be very careful with "initial". Depending on your target architecture it can only be used to initialize ROMs (ASIC) or may create a circuit with very sensitive power-on reset behavior and other oddities (FPGA).

Comment: Ok, I got it. I'll try this. What I need is to initialize some register s' values and if reset is requested, go back to that values. What I've done is to type in the reset block exactly the same that goes in initial, then I thought that must there be some command to go back to the initial.

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of is to use a ROM and use the stored values again at reset.